# Solve a matrix equation..

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, kinematics

I am at moment trying to solve a system of linear equations, and I am not sure if the value I retrieve is even possible, or my program returns some garbage value...

The equation I am trying to solve is:

$$
J(q){\rm d}q = {\rm d}u
$$
where
$J(q) \in\mathbb R^{6\times 7}$, ${\rm d}u\in\mathbb R^6$ and ${\rm d}q$ is the unknown.

So since I have to solve for ${\rm d}q$ I expects its size to be $7\times 1$, as it is the only size that will fit the equation.

The way I solve it by inverting $J(q)$ and multiply it with ${\rm d}u$
$$
{\rm d}q = J(q)^{-1}{\rm d}u
$$
but when I then look at the size of the matrix I see that ${\rm d}q$ is sized $6\times 1$.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How do you invert a non-square matrix?

Comment: using LU factorization...

Comment: if this helps https://gist.github.com/lilac/2464434

Comment: There are numerous posts (on this site, wikipedia, other math sites, you name it) on how to solve non-square systems of equations. Look 'em up!

Comment: @user25778: LU factorization cannot invert a rectangular matrix. I assume your code just dropped a column.

Comment: Well.. yeah linear least square would be an alternative, or is the solution..

Comment: The proper solution is probably the pseudo-inverse (unless your problem needs to be reformulated).

Comment: I just need to compute dq.. and the size of it has to be [7x1]

Comment: hey wait... $J(q)^{−1}du = [6x7][6x1]$ should not be possible to compute at all... ?

Comment: Sorry if I am repeating myself but there is no inverse for a non-square matrix. For $J(q) \in\mathbb R^{m \times n}$, you can find (at most) $\infty^{\left |n-m  \right |}$ matrices $K$ such that $K \cdot J = I$ (and those matrices can help you solve you problem) but finding them is more complex than solving your system of equations.

Comment: I suggest Gauss elimination. If the rank of $J$ is $6$ you will remain with a seventh column of coefficients, that meaning that $dq_{7}=0$ (where the index refers to the last element after the row/column swaps in the Gauss elimination).